# android studio code running is out of order?

Tags: android, android-studio

in this code in Android Studio, getUsers function run after getPosts. But I want them to run in order,how to do that?

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recommend, container, false);
        text = view.findViewById(R.id.test);

          getUsers(new UserListCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCallback(ArrayList<String> users) {
                Log.e("users", users.size()+"" );
               // System.out.println("Loaded "+" contacts");
            }
        });

        getPosts(new UserListCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCallback(ArrayList<String> posts) {
                Log.e("posts", posts.size()+"" );
                // System.out.println("Loaded "+" contacts");
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

```
 private void getPosts(final UserListCallback myCallback) {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.e("p", "pp" + "");

                    Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);

                    posts.add(post.getPostid());
                }
                myCallback.onCallback(posts);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void getUsers(final UserListCallback myCallback) {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.e("si", "fff" + "");
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    Log.e("si", "fff" + "");
                    users.add(user.getId());
                }
                myCallback.onCallback(users);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

 public interface UserListCallback {
        void onCallback(ArrayList<String> value);
    }
```

the output

> E/p: pp 
> pp  
> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for isslod found on class com.example.signup.Model.Post 
> E/p: pp 
> E/posts: 3 
> E/si: fff 
> I/chatty: uid=10159(com.example.signup) identical 11 lines 
> E/si: fff
> E/users: 12

Comment: can you please share the code of getUsers() in your answer

Comment: check the answer in detail you have two queries in your question. the output error  is related to getter and setter in your Post class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your **getPosts()** function inside the result of getUsers.

**Explanation:** It's not related to the android studio framework. You are making a network call which running Asynchronously (*When you execute something asynchronously, you can move on to another task before it finishes*), firebase runs Asynchronously.

Below is your code run the **getPosts()** inside **onDataChange**.

```
private void getUsers(final UserListCallback myCallback) {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.e("si", "fff" + "");
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    Log.e("si", "fff" + "");
                    users.add(user.getId());
                     getPosts();
                }
                myCallback.onCallback(users);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

**regarding the output:** *No setter/field for isslod found on class com.example.signup.Model.Post* you need to create setter and getter in your PojoClass( Post.class)

Open Post.class then press `Alt+ Insert` for Windows or `Command+ N` for Mac in the editor, you may easily generate getter and setter methods for any fields of your class. This has the same effect as using the Menu Bar -> Code -> Generate...

[image: generate setter and getter]